# Error calculating mean, standard error and standard deviation using the ddply function

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the mean, standard error and standard deviation using the ddply apply function but there is not output. There are no 'NA' in this dataset, so missing data shouldn't be an issue. Both habitat and species are factors.

Here is a small sample of my dataset

```
Habitat   Species      Count
   A         T           3
   A         T           4
   A         U           5
   B         V           12
   C         V           3
   D         X           2
```

This is a copy of the code to do the calculations but the output for mean shows as the values for 'Count' in the orignal dataset and all values for sd and se are 'NA'

```
cdata <- ddply(dataset, c("Species", "Habitat"), summarise,
               N    = sum((Count),
               mean = mean(Count),
               sd   = sd(Count),
               se   = sd / sqrt(N))
```

I have also using the summarizeBy() function and aggregate function. 
Would greatly appreciated if someone could advise me on the requirements for using the ddply function and what may be causing this error.

Comment: if you only have one value of count for each grouping then sd will be NA

Answer (score 0):

This code work fine:

```
require(plyr)
require(tidyverse)

dataset <- data.frame(Habitat = c("A","A","A","B","C","D"),
            Species = c("T","T","U","V","V","X"),
            Count = c(3,4,5,12,3,2))

cdata <- ddply(dataset, c("Species", "Habitat"), summarise, N    =sum(Count),mean =mean(Count),sd   =sd(Count)  )

cdata$se <- cdata$sd / cdata$N
```

for `se` computation I add another step for the sake of complexity.